# Apple Time Capsule as encrypted cross-plattform NAS

Tags: encryption, mount, nas, iso-image, time-machine

I would like to use my Apple Time Capsule as an encrypted NAS and the encryption system has to be supported on Linux, MacOsX and optionally Windows. It is important, that the encrypted file system can be mounted to the OS.

I thought, that I could use encrypted Disk Images on the Time Capsule to store the files, but I do not know, which File Format is supported on all plattforms.

Can you give me some ideas?

Answer (score 0):

exFAT, while proprietary to microsoft, has free drivers in linux and OS X.  Whether or not you can format a disk image as exFAT is a different story (I think you can), but whenever I create a flash drive that I need to be supported by the Big Three, I make it exFat.

Having said that, that's for a USB drive being mounted on a machine directly, not over the net.  I don't know if that would work in your situation, but it's worth checking out.